# How can display multiple notifications one after another

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, timer, notifications

I am a bit lost I don't know how to display one notification after another. Let's say for example my current time is "23/11/2021  08:00" and I want to create a reminder for "23/11/2021  09:30" the first time the notification pops up but if I create another reminder for "23/11/2021  09:35" the notification won't show up unless I close the program after the first reminder notification has been displayed and for example if the user sets more than 1 reminder that has the same date and time then only 1 notification should be displayed.

Thanks.

[This is what my form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sUxk.png)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmReminder

    Private CurrentReminderID As Integer = -1

    Private Sub frmReminder_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        BtnClear.PerformClick()
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer2.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Dim CurrentDateTime As Date
    Dim ReminderDateTime As Date

    Public Sub ShowNotification()
        Notification.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Reminder", "Customer Order Due!", ToolTipIcon.None)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DateTimeVariable()
        CurrentDateTime = Date.Now
        CurrentDateTime = FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now, DateFormat.GeneralDate)
        ReminderDateTime = FormatDateTime(ReminderDateTime, DateFormat.GeneralDate)
        If CurrentDateTime = ReminderDateTime Then
            ShowNotification()

        Else
            If DbConnect() Then
                Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
                With SQLCmd
                    .Connection = cn
                    .CommandText = "SELECT ReminderDate FROM TblReminder"
                    Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader()
                        ReminderDateTime = (rs(0))
                End With
            End If
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
        Label6.Text = ""
        TxtCustName.Text = ""
        TxtDeviceInfo.Text = ""
        TxtPrice.Text = ""
        TxtReminderDateTime.ResetText()
        CurrentReminderID = -1
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSetReminder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSetReminder.Click

        If TxtCustName.Text.Length < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Customer name is empty!" & vbCrLf, "Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            TxtCustName.Focus()

        ElseIf TxtDeviceInfo.Text.Length < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Device Information is empty!" & vbCrLf, "Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            TxtDeviceInfo.Focus()

        ElseIf TxtPrice.Text.Length < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No price entered!" & vbCrLf, "Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            TxtPrice.Focus()

        ElseIf DbConnect() Then
            Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
            If CurrentReminderID = -1 Then
                With SQLCmd
                    .Connection = cn
                    .CommandText = "Insert into TblReminder (CustomerName, DeviceInfo, RepairPrice, ReminderDate)"
                    .CommandText &= "Values (@CustomerName, @DeviceInfo, @RepairPrice, @ReminderDate)"
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", TxtCustName.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceInfo", TxtDeviceInfo.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RepairPrice", TxtPrice.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue(" @ReminderDate", TxtReminderDateTime.Text)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()

                    .CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
                    CurrentReminderID = .ExecuteScalar
                    Label6.Text = CurrentReminderID
                    'ShowNotification()
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TxtCustName_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtCustName.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then 'Checks if key pressed isn't a digit
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> Keys.Back Then 'Checks the key pressed wasn't Backspace
                e.Handled = True 'It doesn't take any further action
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TxtPrice_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtPrice.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then 'Checks if key pressed isn't a digit
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> Keys.Back Then 'Checks the key pressed wasn't Backspace
                e.Handled = True 'It doesn't take any further action
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Notification_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Notification.Click
        frmReminderInfo.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Notification_BalloonTipClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Notification.BalloonTipClicked
        frmReminderInfo.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        DateTimeVariable()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnOpenReminders_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOpenReminders.Click
        frmReminderInfo.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        TxtCurrentDateTime.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy      HH:mm")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `BtnClear.PerformClick()` in the Form.Load. How could anything need clearing if the Form is just loading? If you need to call code in an event procedure don't try to simulate the event. Move the code to a separate method and call it from wherever it is needed including the event procedure.

Comment: Users hate it when you check their input on every keystroke. Checking for valid data before it is entered in the database is sufficient. Suppose the user pastes in the data or the customer name contains a number or apostrophe? What if the price has a decimal point?

Comment: Is `Notification` your own class or are you using a 3rd party library? If 3rd party, please let me know which one.

Comment: The "BtnClear.PerformClick()" was inserted into form load just in case there were data entered into the fields and if the user closed the form and opened it again it would clear everything in those fields. I didn't really think about the input check that way but I will change it to what you mentioned. The notification is made by me so no I did not use a 3rd party one.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you could set the Enabled properties of the Timers at design time. I dispensed with the `BtnClear` in comments so I am ignored Form.Load entirely.

```
CurrentDateTime = FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now, DateFormat.GeneralDate)
ReminderDateTime = FormatDateTime(ReminderDateTime, DateFormat.GeneralDate)
```

You cannot assign the a `String` from `FormatDateTime` to `CurrentDataTime` because it is declared as a `Date`. You just assigned a `Date` to it is the line above. Same with `ReminderDateTime`. Keep you dates as `Date` until you need to display them.

I separated the database code from the user interface code. In your `While` loop, you keep overwriting the value of `ReminderDateTime` so that only the final value is in the variable. In view of this I just changed the selection to `Last()` and used `ExecuteScalar`. I don't know why you would want just last date but that is what your code is doing.

```
Private CurrentReminderID As Integer = -1
Private CurrentDateTime As Date
Private ReminderDateTime As Date

Public Sub ShowNotification()
    Notification.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Reminder", "Customer Order Due!", ToolTipIcon.None)
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimeVariable()
    CurrentDateTime = Date.Now
    If CurrentDateTime = ReminderDateTime Then
        ShowNotification()
    Else
        ReminderDateTime = RetrieveReminderDate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function RetrieveReminderDate() As Date
    Dim RemindDate As New Date
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(OPConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Last(ReminderDate) FROM TblReminder", cn)
        cn.Open()
        RemindDate = CDate(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    Return RemindDate
End Function

Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
    Label6.Text = ""
    TxtCustName.Text = ""
    TxtDeviceInfo.Text = ""
    TxtPrice.Text = ""
    DtpReminderDateTime.ResetText()
    CurrentReminderID = -1
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSetReminder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSetReminder.Click
    Dim price As Decimal
    If TxtCustName.Text.Length < 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Customer name is empty!" & vbCrLf, "Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        TxtCustName.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf TxtDeviceInfo.Text.Length < 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Device Information is empty!" & vbCrLf, "Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        TxtDeviceInfo.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not Decimal.TryParse(TxtPrice.Text, price) Then
        MessageBox.Show("No price entered!" & vbCrLf, "Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        TxtPrice.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If CurrentReminderID = -1 Then
            CurrentReminderID = SaveReminder(TxtCustName.Text, TxtDeviceInfo.Text, price, DtpReminderDateTime.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SaveReminder(Name As String, Device As String, Price As Decimal, RemindDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim Id As Integer
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(OPConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into TblReminder (CustomerName, DeviceInfo, RepairPrice, ReminderDate)
                                    Values (@CustomerName, @DeviceInfo, @RepairPrice, @ReminderDate)")
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Name
            .Add("@DeviceInfo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Device
            .Add("@RepairPrice", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Price
            .Add(" @ReminderDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = RemindDate
        End With
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
        Id = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    Return Id
End Function

Private Sub Notification_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Notification.Click
    frmReminderInfo.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Notification_BalloonTipClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Notification.BalloonTipClicked
    frmReminderInfo.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnOpenReminders_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOpenReminders.Click
    frmReminderInfo.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    TxtCurrentDateTime.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy      HH:mm")
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    DateTimeVariable()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I don't want the last date and time, I want to check all of the stored date and times from my database field (ReminderDate) and compare the date and time stored in my database with the current date and time, if comparison is "=" then the notification should be displayed regardless if there is another upcoming reminder in like for example in 5 minutes time.

Comment: @Yousaer10 Please answer my question in comments on your question regarding Notifications.

Comment: @Yousaer10 Regarding ReminderDate, can you edit the code in your question to show what you want?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that the while loop would overwrite so I removed the while loop since you said I kept overwriting the Value of ReminderDateTime.

Comment: I also answered your questions under my post.

Comment: Could you please review my comments?